# iPhone - Can not find my application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a super weird issue. I'm developing an iOS-app and just recently I noticed that I can not find my app on my iPhone. It shows up in the list when searching for the app and when I try to build my app on Xcode it fails because of my app's Core Data model is different from the one I'm building in Xcode. So I need do delete my app from my iPhone but it's hard when I can't find the actual app at all.

I've tried restarting my iPhone to no avail and I have also browsed every screen in the springboard to find my app but it is just not there.

Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 6, when you search for an app in Springboard (the launcher), it shows the name of the folder containing the app (if the app is in a folder).  That might help you find it.

But if you've installed the app using Xcode, there's an easier way to delete it.  Choose Window > Organizer from the menu bar, then click the Devices tab in the Organizer window.  Find your device in the list of devices and click the “Applications” row under your device.  The Organizer will show you a list of all the apps you have installed on the device using Xcode.  You can click on an app in the list, then press the delete key on your keyboard, or click the Delete button at the bottom of the window, to remove the app from the device.

Comment: Perfect, going into the Organizer and deleting from there worked.